# keytool command not running on command prompt. (SHA-1 Key Flutter)

Tags: flutter, keytool

C:\Users\rajmo>-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore
'-alias' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this command from cmd or flutter terminal . go to C:/your profile/ project name/android and then type gradlew signingReport . it will give all SHA-1 and all other certificates.

In my case it look like this -

C:\ronan\facebook\android>gradlew signingReport